# What is a person who has a lot of unimportant ideas in his head called?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who has a lot of ideas, unimportant things, all at once?

Comment: Can you give more example context?  Is "distracted" the word you're looking for?

Comment: Chasing rabbits?

Comment: _Scatterbrained?_

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ideas"? Does he constantly propose *plans* or *explanations* that no-one else is interested in because the things they're intended to solve or explain aren't important? Or does he constantly tell people "objective facts" that they simply think are uninteresting? If the latter, I'd say he's a [*mine of useless information*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mine+of+useless+information%22)

Comment: Scatterbrained - and procrastinator... Those words would work! Thanks!

Comment: Human. Don't we all?

Comment: Way back into the last century, Johnson O'Connor worked for the General Electric Company as an HR specialist. At GE his job was to determine how best to utilize employees by 1) tapping into their innate abilities or aptitudes, and 2) placing them in jobs for which their aptitudes seemed best suited. 

One of the aptitudes O'Connor "discovered" he called ideaphoria, which is the aptitude of being able to tap into a constant flow of ideas. Ideaphoria may or may not be associated with a euphoric state of idea generation and inventiveness. 

  [1]: http://jocrf.org

Comment: As a person who measures high in ideaphoria (I guess you could call me ideaphoric), I recognize this ability in myself as primarily a language-mediated aptitude which gives me no small amount of pleasure--if not euphoria--to me from time to time. 

People who score high in ideaphoria, as measured by a test administered by the [Johnson O'Connor Research Foundation][1], tend to be suited to careers in teaching, advertising, and marketing--to name but three, in which a constant flow of ideas is perhaps *the* sine qua non for those professions in particular.

Comment: I suggest, therefore, that a person who seems never to be at a loss for ideas--an ideaphoric individual--could very well fit into the mold of the person whom you describe. Where an ideaphoric person may *not* fit that mold, however, is in the relative *quality* of the ideas to which he or she has access. 

Indeed, some of those ideas may readily be dismissible. On the other hand, some may contain a nugget which can be mined and may in fact evolve into something pregnant with heuristic possibilities.

Comment: In short, we need ideaphoric people in our world, if only to keep us from getting stuck in a comfortable rut of monotonous predictability and uniformity. Ideas may at times be "a dime a dozen," but there's sometimes gold in them thar hills!

Answer (score 0):

This is what could bring to mind.

**Vacuous**: *Having or showing a lack of thought or intelligence; mindless.*
**Insipid**: *Of a person; senseless, lacking flavor.* 
**Asinine**: *Stupid, foolish, or lacking integrity.* 
**Inane**: *Silly, stupid*.
**Absentminded**: *Having or showing a habitually forgetful or inattentive disposition.*
**Scatterbrained**: *Disorganized and lacking in concentration.*
**Deluded**: *Mislead or foolish.*
**Menial**: *Not requiring much skill and lacking prestige.*

Oxford American College Dictionary.